# How to kill nc -k -l without restart?

Tags: kill, netcat

I have a script running behind the screen which has a command `nc -k -l 12345`. Is there any workarounds I could kill this daemon without restarting the machine?

Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `sudo pkill nc`?

Comment: Thank you. It works. :) But it kills all the nc processes. Is it possible to  find the PID of this specific command and kill that only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that `nc` process was started with exactly that command, and no other `nc` processes have exactly that command, you can do:

```
sudo pkill -fx 'nc -k -l 12345'
```

- `-f` matches the entire command line
- `-x` makes the match exact.